# Scalaz Validation disregard Apply method

Tags: scala, scalaz

```
    (List("ha", "heh", "hmm") |@| List("?", "!", ".")) {_ +"doeswork"+ _}
```

returns correctly

```
     res0: List[String] = List(hadoeswork?, hadoeswork!, hadoeswork., hehdoeswork?, hehdoeswork!, hehdoeswork., hmmdoeswork?, hmmdoeswork!, hmmdoeswork.)
```

while

```
    (Validation.failure[String, String]("fail") |@| Validation.failure[String, String]("fail")) {_ +"doesnotwork"+ _}
```

returns invariably

```
    res1: scalaz.Validation[String,String] = Failure(failfail)
```

whatever function you're passing to "unlift" the values.
Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't do this "invariably". If you tried

```
("fail".success[String] |@| "fail".success[String]) {_ +"doesnotwork"+ _}
```

it would return `Success(faildoesnotworkfail)`. But since not all values passed to `|@|` are `Success`, it doesn't have anything to apply the `{_ + "doesnotwork" + _}` to, because this operation is for the success case, not for the failure case.

The success case is doing the computations. The failure case only returns the combined error messages. If you try to do computations on `Failure`, nothing interesting is actually computed, only the summary of errors is returned.

In your particular case, it just happens to be that it *seems* as if the function is applicable, because both success values and failure messages have the same type. However, in general case, the type of the `failure` messages doesn't even have to do anything with the type of the function passed instead `{_ +"doesnotwork"+ _}`. For example, your `Success` values could be `Double`, and instead of `{_ +"doesnotwork"+ _}` you could then use `{(x, y) => math.atan2(y, x)}`, which wouldn't make any sense for `String`-typed `Failure`-messages.

Comment: Thanks Andrey, makes more sense now!